# Running code on variable set in lua

Tags: lua

I'm writing a script in lua, what i need to do is run a piece of code every time a variable is set.

The code i have is:

```
plane = {}
plane.status = "foo"
plane.status = "bar"
```

I want to run this every time a value is assigned to a variable in plane

```
print "status=" + <value>
```

How would i go about this? i've head it has something to do with __newindex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you set a *proxy* table for `plane` and set a `__newindex` metamethod for it.

```
function managed(t,f)
        return setmetatable({},{__index=t, __newindex=f})
end

plane = managed({},print)
plane.status = "foo"
plane.status = "bar"
```

In practice, in the `__newindex` metamethod, you'll set the values in the original table using `rawset`.

Comment: Note that `__newindex` is called only when *the key is not present the table*. If you want to be able to store the value and also still intercept the calls, you have to store the values in another table, not in the *managed* table.

Comment: @MichalKottman, of course. I meant by *managed* the *original* table. I've edited my answer.